Issue with React Tinder Cards not cycling back around
I'm trying to implement the react tinder but I'm not able to get the cards to cycle back around to the start after the user has exhausted the deck. My code is:
const SwipeImage = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);
  const router = useRouter();
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState(null);

  // used for outOfFrame closure
  const currentIndexRef = useRef(currentIndex);

  const childRefs = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array(images.length)
        .fill(0)
        .map((i, index) => React.createRef()),
    [images]
  );

  const updateCurrentIndex = (val) => {
    setCurrentIndex(val);
    currentIndexRef.current = val;
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImages = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await apiClient.get("/url/", {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.tokens?.access}`,
          },
        });
        const data = response.data;
        const imageUrls = data.map(item => ({
          id: item.id,
          url: item.image,
          name: item.description 
        }));
        setImages(imageUrls);
        setCurrentIndex(imageUrls.length - 1);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch images:", error);
      }
    };

    if (user?.tokens?.access) {
      fetchImages();
    }
  }, [user?.tokens?.access]);

  const canGoBack = currentIndex < images.length - 1;
  const canSwipe = currentIndex >= 0;

  const swiped = (direction, nameToDelete, index) => {
    setLastDirection(direction);
    if (index === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        updateCurrentIndex(images.length - 1); // Reset to the last card in the list
      }, 500); // delay to allow the last card to swipe out before resetting
    } else {
      updateCurrentIndex(index - 1);
    }
  };

  const outOfFrame = (name, idx) => {
    console.log(`${name} (${idx}) left the screen!`, currentIndexRef.current);
  };

  const swipe = async (dir) => {
    if (canSwipe && currentIndex < images.length) {
      await childRefs[currentIndex].current.swipe(dir); 
    }
  };

  const goBack = async () => {
    if (!canGoBack) return;
    const newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    updateCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    await childRefs[newIndex].current.restoreCard();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
      </Head>
      <div className="swipe-tinder-cards-container">
        {images.length > 0 ? (
          images.map((image, index) => (
            <TinderCard
              ref={childRefs[index]}
              className="swipe-swipe"
              key={image.id}
              onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, image.name, index)}
              onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(image.name, index)}
              preventSwipe={['up', 'down']}
            >
              <div
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image.url})` }}
                className="swipe-card"
              >
                <h3>{image.name}</h3>
              </div>
            </TinderCard>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className='swipe-buttons'>
        <button style={{ backgroundColor: !canSwipe && '#c3c4d3' }} onClick={() => swipe('left')}>Swipe left!</button>
        <button style={{ backgroundColor: !canGoBack && '#c3c4d3' }} onClick={() => goBack()}>Undo swipe!</button>
        <button style={{ backgroundColor: !canSwipe && '#c3c4d3' }} onClick={() => swipe('right')}>Swipe right!</button>
      </div>
      {lastDirection ? (
        <h2 key={lastDirection} className='swipe-infoText'>
          You swiped {lastDirection}
        </h2>
      ) : (
        <h2 className='swipe-infoText'>
          Swipe a card or press a button to get Restore Card button visible!
        </h2>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default SwipeImage;

The buttons and cards work fine, but I just want to loop back around rather than end with a blank screen. My current solution is with the swiped const but it is not working correctly.

Can you share a link for sandbox or fiddle so that it would be easier to help?
